# Wikidata SPARQL query: how to get values of the property 'applies to part' (P518)

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

on the page describing Hurricane Ian on wikidata [Ian wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q114160017), we can consult which parts of countries were concerned by the event (Florida, Georgia, etc.)

I'm trying to write a query to get these information via a python script:

```
SELECT distinct ?label ?item ?superTypeLabel ?date ?start_date ?end_date  ?countryLabel   ?countryPart
WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q63100601;
              wdt:P31 ?superType;
              rdfs:label ?label.
      ?superType rdfs:label ?superTypeLabel.
       # with a point in time or start date
       FILTER langMatches(lang(?label),'en').
       FILTER langMatches(lang(?superTypeLabel),'en').
           # with a point in time or start date
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P585 ?date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P580 ?date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P580 ?start_date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P582 ?end_date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P17 ?country. 
             ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel. 
             FILTER langMatches(lang(?countryLabel),'en').}
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P518 ?countryPart. }
    # but at least one of those
    FILTER(BOUND(?date) && DATATYPE(?date) = xsd:dateTime).
    # not in the future, and not more than 31 days ago
    BIND(NOW() - ?date AS ?distance).
    FILTER(0 <= ?distance && ?distance < 365).
    FILTER contains(?label,"Hurricane Ian") 
      }
```

the previous query works well, except for the ?countryPart values, the query doesn't return any value while on the HTML page the information is well represented. any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get country parts by adding the following line :

```
OPTIONAL { ?item  p:P17 [ps:P17 ?country; pq:P518 ?countryPart] }
```

the final query:

```
SELECT distinct ?label ?item ?superTypeLabel ?date ?start_date ?end_date  ?country   ?countryPart
WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q63100601;
              wdt:P31 ?superType;
              rdfs:label ?label.
      ?superType rdfs:label ?superTypeLabel.
       # with a point in time or start date
       FILTER langMatches(lang(?label),'en').
       FILTER langMatches(lang(?superTypeLabel),'en').
           # with a point in time or start date
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P585 ?date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P580 ?date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P580 ?start_date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P582 ?end_date. }
    OPTIONAL { ?item  p:P17 [ps:P17 ?country; pq:P518 ?countryPart] }
    # but at least one of those
    FILTER(BOUND(?date) && DATATYPE(?date) = xsd:dateTime).
    # not in the future, and not more than 31 days ago
    BIND(NOW() - ?date AS ?distance).
    FILTER(0 <= ?distance && ?distance < 365).
    FILTER contains(?label,"Hurricane Ian") 
      }
```